# How to download playalist except certain videos in youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

I want to download a play list from youtube, where the first 6 videos in the playlist have been deleted by their channel. When I tried to download it using youtube-dl, it's getting interupted because the first video was not found. Then it is terminating, but not continuing to download the next video. How can I download the playlist from the 7nth video in the play list and onwards.

the command I used.

```
youtube-dl -f 22 https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLO-hrPk0zuI18xlF_480s6UiaGD7hBqJa
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following switch:

```
 --playlist-items ITEM_SPEC       Playlist video items to download. Specify
                                     indices of the videos in the playlist
                                     separated by commas like: "--playlist-items
                                     1,2,5,8" if you want to download videos
                                     indexed 1, 2, 5, 8 in the playlist. You can
                                     specify range: "--playlist-items
                                     1-3,7,10-13", it will download the videos
                                     at index 1, 2, 3, 7, 10, 11, 12 and 13.
```

So it would be:

```
youtube-dl -f 22 --playlist-items 7-X https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLO-hrPk0zuI18xlF_480s6UiaGD7hBqJa
```

where X is the number of videos in the playlist.

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 4):

`youtube-dl` has an option `-i` which will do what you asked, skip the deleted/restricted items and download anything in the play list that is available. See the “Options” section of the manual page (`man youtube-dl`).

Comment: Please format your answer!